# The "--routePrefix" option does not exist error found

Tags: laravel

when this line executes

```php
$process = new Process('php artisan api:generate --routePrefix="v1" --header="Authorization: Bearer '. $token. '" --router="dingo" --force --output documentation --bindings="user,1|city,London|date,2009-01-01"');
```

this error shown

> The "--routePrefix" option does not exist

Comment: What package are you using? where did you get the `api:generate` command from?

Comment: I have use mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator

Comment: when I use api:generate its work but when execute command php artisan make:documentation to execute the command which I created, the problem  was happen

Comment: I wanted to use an api document generator with composer require mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator, then I used the api:generate --routePrefix="api/*" command.